# ¿Como puedo cambiar el brillo con un slider?

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Buenos dias tengo un problema con el codigo de unity y es que quiero con el slider hacer un cambio de brillo, pero nose porque no me sirve, soy nuevo asi porfavor entiendamen, que error tendre si alguien me puede ayudar estaría agradecido

aqui muestro el codigo implementado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La linea de código del Update "brilloSlider.value = brillo", deberia ir en Start ya que solo quieres que la barra se establezca su valor al iniciarse dicho script. Aparte de esto, que error tienes exactamente ? Ya que indicas lo que quieres hacer, pero no mencionas cual es el problema.

Comment: Hola, el error que tengo es que no me esta cambiando el brillo, me aparece nullReferenceExecption, ya lo cambie a Start y sigue igual, nose que estare haciendo mal

Comment: En la segunda imagen veo que te falta agregar el slider al inspector, simplemente arrastra el GameObject slider al inspector en la parte "Brillo Slider". Si tu problema es que no cambia tu valor float brillo dando el error, la solución es simplemente esa. Si te refieres a que el brillo no cambia, necesitaría saber que brillo exactamente es el que quieres cambiar.

Comment: mira esto es lo que quiero hacer con el brillo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihT0chhWZ4Q&t=682s , minuto 11:10, como haria mire el video pero no entiendo unas cosas asi que me aconsejas hacer

Comment: Para poder ayudar mejor, necesitarías poner el código que tienes hasta el momento para ver donde está el problema. De todos modos, viendo el video muestra el código completo. Así que si tienes una duda especifica, también puedes agregarla a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte.